# First Betti number of a Reeb graph is not greater than that of the space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, computational-geometry

It is well-known that $\beta_1(R(f))\le\beta_1(X)$, where $\beta_1$ is the first Betti number (number of loops), $X$ is a topological space, $f:X\to\mathbb R$ a continuous funcion, and $R(f)$ its Reeb graph, i.e., the space of contours of $f$ (connected components of levels of $f$): see, e.g., [Computational Topology: An Introduction](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=MDXa6gFRZuIC&lpg=PA145&dq=reeb%20graph&pg=PA141#v=onepage&q=reeb%20graph&f=false) by Edelsbrunner & Harer, page 141.

However, the commonly given argument looks flawed to me: it is said that the dimensionality of the space of **images** of all 1-cycles of $X$ in $R(f)$ does not exceed $\beta_1(X)$, but why cannot $R(f)$ have other 1-cycles not induced from any 1-cycle of $X$?

For example, the height function $f$ on a Warsaw circle (a topologist's sine curve including a segment at the "bad" place, not just a point; plus a piece of a circle) $X$:

[image] or even [image]

(EDIT 2: The left picture is not a counterexample, but the variant of the function at the right is.)

is continuous and $R(f)$ is a circle, $\beta_1(R(f))=1$, while $\beta_1(X)=0$ ([here](http://www2.math.su.se/reports/2008/4/2008-4.pdf), Remark 2.7 on page 7). While it is true that the projection in $R(f)$ of any cycle in $X$ is zero, $R(f)$ has a cycle not projected from any cycle in $X$.

Where am I wrong?

And even if this particular counterexample is wrong, still how to prove that $R(f)$ does not have other cycles?

EDIT 1:

Here is the statement from the book:

[image]

and then:

[image]

So I want to understand whether the fact is true, and why.

Comment: I think you should spell out  the precise definition of the Reeb graph (link rot). Also, I think, in applications, $f$ is meant to be a smooth function on a smooth manifold (maybe even a Morse function). In general, I suppose, you need to use Chech cohomology to deal with pathological examples such as the one you gave.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I added the definition and the statement from the book; I think here singular homology is meant (yes, in Cech homology a similar, but different, statement is probably true, but needs a proof). I know applications deal with easy cases, but I wonder whether the statement is true as formulated here, i.e., for a general case.

Comment: I am nearly sure that the claim is false for general spaces if singular homology is used. In the case of Morse functions on smooth manifolds, you can prove the inequality by using Mayer-Vietoris sequence (singular homology suffices). As for what they wrote, it is just sloppy math, not un-typical for applied mathematicians.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Consider the picture at the right (polygon chain) with the height function. Each value of $f$, except top and bottom extrema, has two preimage components: one on the left (on the straight line) and one on the right (on the polygon chain). The left components form a segment homeomorphic the left-hand straight line. And so do the right ones; as far as I understand, this set is homeomorphic to a segment, too. The two segments are connected at the extrema to form a circle. Am I wrong?

Comment: Right, I misunderstood the definition.